# Laravel 5.3 Declare global session var after login success

Tags: laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5.3

I've got Auth logins set up on my web app and it works correctly. However, after the user logs in I want to set a global variable like so:

```
// Store a piece of data in the session...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

However, I'm a little lost as to where I should declare a variable after the user successfully logs in.

Should I be doing that in the app/http/controllers/auth/logincontroller.php
file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3 you can override [`authenticated()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L114) method in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`:

```
protected function authenticated()
{
    session(['key' => 'value']);
}
```

In Laravel 5.2 you can override [`login()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L57) method in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`.

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/JT-APP/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 103 and defined